# Tell EF6 Not to Persist Base Class but set FluentAPI contrains

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a base class called "Entity" in which I put standard fields that should be inherited by ever entity (ex. Id, CreateAt, UpdateAt). I prefer to use FluentAPI as it is said to be more powerful then annotations and it enables clean easily readable POCO classes. Is there a way I can set up attributes on those fields in fluent api for the parent entity class and have it inherited but also not generate a table in the database for the "Entity" POCO class?

Comment: can't you just mark the base class abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal entity configuration would be something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Planet>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
}
```

However, as you have noticed, this will also register the type as part of your model. Entity Framework 6 though introduced the [`DbModelBuilder.Types<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.types(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Types%60%601) method which according to the docs:

> Begins configuration of a lightweight convention that applies to all entities and complex types in the model that inherit from or implement the type specified by the generic argument. **This method does not register types as part of the model.**

That means you can configure your base entity class like this:

```
modelBuilder.Types<Entity>().Configure(c =>
{
    c.HasKey(e => e.Id);
});
```

Which saves you having to do it for every type that inherits from `Entity`.

Comment: So let me get this straight. Do I still need to create the Entity POCO class. And then have my other entities inherit from it. Or do I do this instead of my Entity class?

Comment: After I read your response I came across this. modelBuilder.Ignore<Entity>();. Would this work for me? Because I may not want every entity create to have these properties. Just the ones I specifically Inherit from Entity.

Comment: With this you will still have the `Entity` class. I don't have anything to test on right now, but I suspect that `Ignore<Entity>` will cascade down to all of your entities in the same way you had the initial problem.

Comment: I have tried it. It works. I don't mind having the entity class as it is good for documentation. I just didn't want it to generate  a table in the database. But i wanted to be able to configure the inherited fields.